# Step By Step : Making a server accessible worldwide

Tags: networking, server, apache2, mysql

I am new to Ubuntu Server, and in general with servers, so consider me as a beginner... (But, I know how to use the terminal.)

Note: I use a router, not a modem nor a broadband connection. The internet connection speed is VDSL (50MBPS)

Now, the Question:

I am going to set up a server using an old PC, and do the following steps:

1. Install Lubuntu (Because the PC is a low-end netbook)
2. Install TaskSel (sudo apt-get install tasksel)
3. Run TaskSel (sudo tasksel), select OpenSSH and click Install
4. Update the software
5. Install the required server software (sudo apt-get install apache2 php5-mysql libapache2-mod-php5 mysql-server)
6. I will run "ifconfig | grep inet" to find the IP, and test the IP to another PC on the Local Network to see if it works. Logically, it will so the "It Works!" page.
7. I will restart the PC.
8. I will install WordPress and create a database for it.
9. I will move WordPress files to the /var/www directory and gain access to it by using the following commands:

sudo usermod -g www-data [YOUR USERNAME]

sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www

sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www

10. That's the step I need help.  I need to set the IP as static, but I don't know if this has to be done from the router settings, from Lubuntu Settings, or from both. So, please tell me how to do that.
11. As I read, to make the site accessible from worldwide, I need to create a DMZ. And to do this, I will need to go to the router settings, find DMZ settings, and add the IP on the field there

Thanks in advance for help.

Also, I have searched the forum, and found interesting stuff, but I couldn't find step-by-step answer to the step 10. Sorry if there is one answer that is step-by-step for my question and I didn't find it.

Comment: Because I am in holidays and I use a metered connection, I have not got enough megabytes to search a lot...

Answer (score 0):

to build a simple DMZ and set up your server worldwide, you can get a broadband connection with static IP address, then you can connect your "server" to your modem and configure port forwarding on it.

For example, you can forward external port 8888 to 192.168.1.100:80

this way, if a user connects to your modem's IP address but with port 8888, the connection will be redirected to 192.168.1.100 which is your server's IP address.

comment if you have any questions and I'll answer it to you.

Comment: Thanks for the immediate reply. My problem is that I have a normal connection to the internet using a router(vdsl speed if matters)

Comment: i use a router not a modem, and i will connect wired to the net (with cable)

Comment: go into your modem/router's configuration and see if it supports Virtual Server or Port Forwarding. Then configure it as I mentioned in the post and see if you can reach your Apache server using your modem's IP address.

Comment: ok, but what is DMZ and whats the real different from port forwarding?

Comment: should i enable both dmz and port forwarding, or not

Comment: They're actually the same concept. Some routers refer to them as DMZ, normal Routers (For SOHO use) usually refer to them as Virtual Server or Port Forwarding. It's really all about the other layers of security which is clearly not your case (eg. firewall)

Comment: Port forwarding would suffice. DMZ makes the computer unavailable to other VLANS.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26763/discussion-between-haris-linuxos-and-alireza-mosajjal).

Comment: OK, I will try DUckDNS because it is not allowed by my isp to set static the ip, And I will notify you about the results

Comment: @HarisLinuxOS great. looking forward to it.